# What are the video formats supported by MPMoviePlayerController on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

When you use iTunes to sync your videos with the iPhone the videos are always saved with no more than 640 pixels wide, if I am not wrong.

What about the iPad? What is the size of videos iTunes syncs with iPad? 1024x768? and what if the video has a dimension below 1024x768? Will it scale up? or will it keep the video at low res and scale when you play?

The question is because I am using the MPMoviePlayerController and I need to know what resolutions to expect, so I can adjust the interface.

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the MPMoviePlayerController docs:

***Supported Formats***
This class supports any movie or audio files that already play correctly on an iPod or iPhone. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,.mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:
  1. H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
  2. MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

And yes, you can scale up to fit your view or go full screen, same as on iPhone.

Comment: thanks. 640x480 even on iPad???  So, any video the user has on its library will be 640x480, so I will never have to worry about the user selecting a video larger than that on my app right? But how do you explain that I have tested right now, playing a 1024x768 movie contained in my app, and it played right fine at superb resolution??

Comment: I can confirm that I also have run a 1024x768 movie full screen on the iPad, and to my uneducated eyes it looks fine.  But the above is what the Apple docs say.