# Many types of video types not working with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ogg, mpeg, webm

I am finding that there are many types of files that just don't work with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 5.1. They include webm, ogv, flv (of course), mpeg2, and a few more that I forgot. Is there any way to improve the chances of playback of these files, other than converting them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not suport all the fileformat/codecs. you can refer to to know the supported formats
[What are the video formats supported by MPMoviePlayerController on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719214/what-are-the-video-formats-supported-by-mpmovieplayercontroller-on-the-ipad)

other options would be writing your own application to decode n display (but its not practical)