# Why can I play one movie in MPMoviePlayer but not an other movie?

Tags: mpmovieplayer

I have implemented a MPMoviePlayer in my app and when I try it with a sample video in .mov format it works well. But when I change movie-clip to a .mP4 or m4v it does not work, the app crashes (I have tried with a bunch of different movie-files. What can be wrong? Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the video formats supported by MPMoviePlayerController on the iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719214/what-are-the-video-formats-supported-by-mpmovieplayercontroller-on-the-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your question, but I did a quick search on supported file formats.

Another S.O. Answer:

> Supported Formats
>   This class supports any movie or audio files that already play correctly on an iPod or iPhone. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files. For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov, .mp4,.mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression standards:
>   1. H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
>   2. MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
>   If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

So that would be my guess why :)
Coulndt you just convert to MOV ?

Edit:
Link to SO answer where quote is taken from:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719214/what-are-the-video-formats-supported-by-mpmovieplayercontroller-on-the-ipad)